# jQuery button container widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The widget shall behave in the following way: As I press on a button, it would appear a "container" which can contain multiple icon-buttons. What is the appropriate container?

I have tried to use jQuery dialog but it seems that it's difficult to use. Do I have another choice? Or is it just that I don't know how to use the jQuery dialog?

Please give me some guidance, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm seems jQuery UI Dialog and Buttons should do the trick.

**See: http://jsfiddle.net/vQuGU/**

Or do you want something different?

Comment: It is close. But I want to use my own image-icon. 
like this kind of button:
<button>
<img src= "pic/asdfasd.png">
</button>

Comment: Well are you getting the icon from serverside? Else you just give the icon function a custom class, like `ui-icon-asdfasd` and then in your css do `.ui-icon-asdfasd {background-image: url('pic/asdfasd.png') no-repeat;` else you could just have an image tag inside the button element like you wrote, see http://jsfiddle.net/vQuGU/1/

Comment: Not the custom class only. I need the serverside. I'll try to use 
.class and tag method. But I don't know if it will work or not.

Comment: See the jsfiddle ( jsfiddle.net/vQuGU/1 ) you can easily do it that way. But the CSS way is ofcourse more dynamic and pretty (you can easy change the icon for the same function without editing serverside code).

Answer (score 0):

Try [jquery overlay](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html)

Comment: It is close. But I want to use my own image-icon. 
like this kind of button:
<button>
<img src= "pic/asdfasd.png">
</button>